# Android Navigation Back (hamburger) always brings out drawer

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, back-button, android-navigation, android-jetpack-navigation

So I've built an app with a few main pages as top level destination fragments. Users can click within the main pages (one, two, three, etc) to bring up more details fragments *(page_one_item1_details, page_two_item3_details, etc)*. When doing so, the hamburger button changes to a back arrow as expected.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

  private AppBarConfiguration mAppBarConfiguration;

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    initViews();
  }

  private void initViews() {
    final Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    final DrawerLayout drawerLayout = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);

    final NavController navController = Objects.requireNonNull(
        (NavHostFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.nav_host_fragment))
        .getNavController();

    mAppBarConfiguration = new AppBarConfiguration.Builder(
        R.id.nav_home,
        R.id.nav_main_page_one,
        R.id.nav_main_page_two,
        R.id.nav_main_page_three,
        R.id.nav_main_page_four)
        .setOpenableLayout(drawerLayout).build();

    NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this, navController, mAppBarConfiguration);
    NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(
        (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view), navController);
    
    final ActionBarDrawerToggle actionBarDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
        this, drawerLayout, toolbar, R.string.drawer_open,
        R.string.drawer_close) {

      @Override
      public void onDrawerSlide(final View drawerView, final float slideOffset) {
        super.onDrawerSlide(drawerView, slideOffset);
        ((InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE))
            .hideSoftInputFromWindow(drawerView.getWindowToken(), 0);
      }
    };
    drawerLayout.addDrawerListener(actionBarDrawerToggle);
    actionBarDrawerToggle.syncState();
  }

  @Override
  public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(final Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
  }

  @Override
  public boolean onSupportNavigateUp() {
    return NavigationUI.navigateUp(
        Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment), mAppBarConfiguration)
        || super.onSupportNavigateUp();
  }
}
```

If I click the Android back button, the app will go back to a main page fragment as expected, but if I click the top back-button (in place of the hamburger) it brings up the drawer instead of going back.
Can anyone tell if I'm missing something? Do I need to alter my MainActivity code, or do I have to put some code elsewhere? I've tried a couple variations in the above code to onSupportNavigateUp but it still always brings up the drawer.

I have also tried:

```
return Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment), drawerLayout)
        || super.onSupportNavigateUp();
```

and

```
NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment);
    return NavigationUI.navigateUp(navController, mAppBarConfiguration)
        || super.onSupportNavigateUp()
```

*note - even removing onSupportNavigateUp still always brings up the drawer under all circumstances. No back functionality.*

Answer (score 0):

I had to remove my whole:

```
final ActionBarDrawerToggle actionBarDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
        this, drawerLayout, toolbar, R.string.drawer_open,
        R.string.drawer_close) {

      @Override
      public void onDrawerSlide(final View drawerView, final float slideOffset) {
        super.onDrawerSlide(drawerView, slideOffset);
        ((InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE))
            .hideSoftInputFromWindow(drawerView.getWindowToken(), 0);
      }
    };
    drawerLayout.addDrawerListener(actionBarDrawerToggle);
    actionBarDrawerToggle.syncState();
```

Everything behaves as I would expect it would now with the up-back-hamburger button going back/up when it's a back-arrow and brings up the drawer when it's a hamburger.

I started this project off an example project so I left that part in without every studying what ActionBarDrawerToggle is or does. Spending time on the Googles now...

Answer (score 0):

Do not use `ActionBarDrawerToggle`.

From the android developer site:
[override onSupportNavigateUp() to handle Up navigation](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-ui#java)

```
@Override
public boolean onSupportNavigateUp() {
    NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment);
    return NavigationUI.navigateUp(navController, appBarConfiguration)
            || super.onSupportNavigateUp();
}
```